# Getting Nginx to serve static files from several sources

Tags: nginx, static-files

I have a Nginx config that works fine and serves static files properly:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /tmp/static/;
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
}
```

But what I want to do now is that if the static file doesn't exist in `/tmp/static`, Nginx looks for the file in `/srv/www/site/static`. I am not sure how to achieve that, I have tried a few things with `try_files`, but I don't know how to properly use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set your root to the common prefix of the two paths you want to use (in this case, it's /), then just specify the rest of the paths in the try_files args:

```
location /static/ {
  root /;
  try_files /tmp$uri /srv/www/site$uri =404;
  expires 30d;
  access_log off;
}
```

It may seem disconcerting to use root / in a location, but the try_files will ensure that no files outside of /tmp/static or /srv/www/site/static will be served.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work with $uri, when I use $request_uri it does, any idea why?

Comment: $request_uri expands to the original, unprocessed uri path from the request line.  It is unaffected by any internal redirects.  $uri is the current uri path being processed, and it is changed by internal redirects.  I'd guess that you're somehow internally redirecting and that's causing your issue.

Answer (score 2):

the following should do the trick:

```
location /static/ {
  expires 30d;
  access_log off;
  try_files tmp/static/$uri tmp/static/$uri/ tmp/static2/$uri tmp/static2/$uri/;
}
```

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files for documentation and examples of try_files use

Answer (score 2):

You can use a named location with "root" in order to process a series of fallback locations.  Note that you cannot use "alias" inside a named location.

```
location / {
    root /path/to/primary/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
}
location @fallback {
    root /path/to/secondary/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your needs would be served by using the [SlowFS Cache Module](http://labs.frickle.com/nginx_ngx_slowfs_cache/). It caches your static content in a temporary directory that is presumably stored on faster disks, and manages the fallback for you.